# Firebase OTP in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

When I try with Azerbaijan (+994) numbers, doesn't work. "CodeSent" doesn't trigger. But when I try other countries' numbers, It works and "codeSent" triggers.

I tried some solutions but It didn't help. I don't think I made something wrong in Firebase or Flutter.